# XCode and Objective-C warning

Tags: objective-c, warnings

Could someone please tell me what this means : 
I got this in the console at the application launch.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints` that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the `UIView` property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`)

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x769a0c0 V:[UIImageView:0x769a030(1150)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x769cd40 V:[UIImageView:0x769a030]-(-550)-|   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7699cc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x769ccc0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x769a030]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7699cc0 )>"
)
```

Comment: I don't think anyone here can help actually help you, unless you provide us with a little bit more. All I can say is, that there's something wrong with an Imageview within a ScrollView. Is the Imageview larger than the Scrollview, or maybe out of bounds?

Comment: Yes, true. I have an imageview that is larger than the scrollvView. But why is that a warning? I am trying to zoom and pan using scrollView.

Comment: According to the error message you posted, you probably have some autoresizing in place, which is failing. (Maybe because it conflicts with the scrollview).

Comment: okie, let me look at it. This is atleast a start.